# How to interact with net.core linux service?

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to write a linux service which listen to commands from console, a basic service or background process for example written in c# and running on linux machine.

I have a method in my app:

namespace MyApp
{
public void Echo(string input)
{
Console.WriteLine(input);
}
}
What do i need to do to let the user interact with my background service?

I am not so familiar with linux but i want it to be something like "MyApp Echo 'hello world'"
Or systemd MyApp..

Thank you.